# After click button _POST method inserts empty row

Tags: php, jquery

this is my code HTML:

```
<form  method="post" id ="myform">
<p>
    <label for="tytul">Tytuł :</label>
    <input type="text" name="tytul" id="tytul">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="opis">Opis:</label>
    <input type="text" name="opis" id="opis">
</p>

<input type="submit" class = "button" name = "Dodaj" value = "Dodaj" id="btn" >
```

After click "btn" button my jQuery script is working:

```
    $('#btn').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'gra.php?call=true',
    type:'GET',
    success:function(data){
    body.append(data);
    }
  });
})
```

This is my php code:

```
   <?php
           //DODAWANIE REKORDU 
           
 if(isset($_GET['call'])) 
           { 
           $tytul = htmlentities('tytul', ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
       $opis = htmlentities('opis', ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
           $nazwa = $login_session;
  $state = 1;
           $tytul = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['tytul']);
$opis = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['opis']);
$sqladd = "INSERT INTO tasks (tytul, opis, state, login ) VALUES ('$tytul', '$opis', '$state', '$nazwa' )";
if(mysqli_query($db, $sqladd)){
    echo "Rekord pomylsnie dodany.";
    
} else{
   echo "ERROR";
}
 mysqli_close($db);
// Close connection

           }
        ?>
```

Problem is that my "tytul" and "opis" variables are "". My row is inserted to database but with empty columns. Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Hi, you are not passing any value in ajax call .

Comment: Here's what your code does:  click button / run click handler / *start* an ajax call / exit click handler / continue with button click, button is a submit button, so POST the form ... sometime later... "receive" ajax call (but doesn't receive it as it's no longer on the page).   **edit** so from other comments, I'm guessing the form POST does nothing (that's not where the empty saves are coming from) - you should cancel the form POST  (I couldn't [be bothered to] read that PHP code as it's too badly formatted, so skipped it :) )

Comment: Shortest description of the problem: you're not preventing default behaviour of your form submit. Researching that should get you on the right track.

Comment: This is what i did : add -  " data: {status: status, name: name}, " but it doesnt work at all now. Sorry for noob questions i am just learning :)

Comment: Not a php developer, but I would imagine if you attempt to read `$_POST['tytul']` then that would only be available for a `type:"POST"` and *not* a `type:"GET"`.   If you remove `if(isset($_GET['call']))` then it will pick up the values from the `form` post. I'd get that working first (as simple form POST without ajax) then add an ajax *POST* (not GET) with data - make sure the `data: { var: value }` matches the `$_POST['var']`  (your php doesn't reference "status" or "name")

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have form action as "post" and button type as submit and having click event for button. So, if you click button, it will do form post. So, remove the form post action attribute and change button type as button. Change the HTML like below and try:

```
<form id="myform">
<p>
   <label for="tytul">Tytuł :</label>
   <input type="text" name="tytul" id="tytul">
</p>
<p>
   <label for="opis">Opis:</label>
   <input type="text" name="opis" id="opis">
</p>
<input type="button" class = "button" name = "Dodaj" value = "Dodaj" id="btn" >
```

Comment: Thanks i improved my code follow to your comment but still nothing in "opis" and "tytul" rows. I added "data" to jquery:              $('#btn').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'gra.php?call=true',
    type:'GET',
 data :{ opis : opis }
    success:function(data){
    body.append(data);
    }
  });
})

Comment: Can you try : Instead of $_POST to $_GET:
   $tytul = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['tytul']);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, solution to my problem was adding `data: $("#registerSubmit").serialize(),` to ajax code. And @freedomn-m + @Gowtham tips